# Who can modify a managed package?

Tags: managed-package, package

Can managed packages only be modified by the people who distributed that managed package?

Answer (score 7):

The majority of packaged components can only be modified by the Package developer in the Packaging org. There are some exceptions, for example you can modify certain aspects of managed components in the subscriber org (i.e. where its installed), such as field descriptions and field sets etc.

This [guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm) gives you a list of what can and can't be changed and by who and when. If you're the user of the managed package, probably the column "Subscriber and Developer Editable" is most applicable.

Comment: Another source of information, specifically around managed packages, is [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm).